# HDRI error not properly when show up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, hdri

everyone can you help me with this problem?
i still use blender 2.79 [image]
hdri not properly show up.

actually, I got one problem too but I forget to take a screenshot, when a textured object seen in rendered mode to object will have an abstract shape.

Thank you

Comment: In orthographic view, you can only see one point on the HDR because the camera frustum doesn't grow larger as it gets further away from the camera.

Comment: thank you its can now